# Orleans Performance

Tags: documentation, orleans

I have recently been diving deeply into Orleans and have been having trouble trying to specs to validate against MVC micro services. I am also not sure what an optimal setup would be in Azure for processing power/ram to traffic ratio. Has anyone found documentation around these premises?

Comment: One specific question per post is best.